# Fade and rotate between images continuously

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I am trying to find code to fade and rotate between images continuously. I downloaded script which works on JSFiddle but not when I apply to my website. . Can someone help me? Here is the code:

```
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">


     $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
                         .next('img')
                         .fadeIn()
                         .end()
                         .appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 4000); // 4 seconds


    </script>

     </head>

      <style>

     .fadein {
       position:relative;
        height:320px;
        width:320px;
    }

    .fadein img {
         position:absolute;
         left:0;
         top:0;
    }

     </style>

 <div class="fadein">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8359/8450229021_9d660578b4_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8510/8452880627_0e673b24d8_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8108/8456552856_a843b7a5e1_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8230/8457936603_f2c8f48691_n.jpg">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8447290659_02c4765928_n.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you include jQuery plugin? What is the error your seeing in console.Also please share jsfiddle link

Comment: Can you give me the JSFiddle link that it works?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/2kkHH/

Comment: When I edit the code to include the JQuery plugin I download it still doesn't work. As shown below.

<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you're including Jquery, either from a CDN or in a script tag that accurately references the Jquery file. For example, if Jquery-1.12.0.min.js is in your js folder, your script looks like:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then, put your rotator script at the end of your page, or wrap in a document.ready function like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        //all your codes
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to accept the answer!